# .htaccess redirect if domain is not X

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect trought .htaccess if the domain is not:

- www.domain.tld
- domain.tld

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?domain.tld [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.tld/ [L,R=301,QSD]
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

You should also pass your grouping as a backreference using `$1` or use the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?domain.tld [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301,QSD]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?domain.tld [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]
```

Note that `QSD` is an apache 2.4 rewrite flag, it won't work with apache 2.2. If you're using apache 2.2 and want to remove the query string, just add a `?` to the end of the target:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.tld/$1? [L,R=301,QSD]
```